# Is using Image Recognition (CNN) to play Flappy Bird feasible? (No Q learning or Genetic algorithm or anything else)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

This is my first post, and everything I know is self taught so I apologise in advance for any mistakes I make. Do let me know if there are more things I need to include. Thanks

This idea is to feed a cnn screenshots of flappy bird as it runs and have the network predict if the agent should hit spacebar or do nothing.

I have trained a model that achieves around 0.9874 acc and 0.99 val_acc. When testing the model, the bird knocks itself into the pipe most of the time, with only a few attempts where it gets a score of 2 before dying.

Is it possible to use purely image recognition to train the agent well? (more details below)

Trained on following data:
(image, [1,0])
(image, [0,1])
.
.
.

Where [1,0] is jump and [0,1] is do nothing.

Trained on 10 000 images(8000 of which are augmented) and validated on 6000(4800 are augmented) getting the following results:

Epoch 50/50
10081/10081 [==============================] - 63s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0527 - acc: 0.9874 - val_loss: 0.0176 - val_acc: 0.9954

```py
from keras.models import load_model
from grabscreen import grab_screen
import cv2
import time
from directkeys import PressKey,ReleaseKey, Space
from getkeys import key_check
import numpy as np
import time


model = load_model('models/flappy_model_4_hl_2fcl_5aug_shuff_50epoch_287.h5')

def jump():
    PressKey(Space)
    ReleaseKey(Space)

def main():
    last_time = time.time()
    #countdown
    for i in list(range(4))[::-1]:
        print(i+1)
        time.sleep(1)

    paused = False

    screen = grab_screen(region=(0,200,600,800))
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    prev = cv2.resize(screen, (150,250))

    while True:

        if not paused:
            screen = grab_screen(region=(0,200,600,800))
            screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            #last_time = time.time()
            screen = cv2.resize(screen, (150,250))
            screen = [[screen]]
            #print(np.shape(screen))

            prediction = model.predict(screen)[0]
            prediction = np.around(prediction)
            prediction = prediction[0]
            print(prediction)

            last_time = time.time()
            if prediction == 1:
                jump()
                time.sleep(0.2)
                #print('Jump')

            #print('Loop took: ' + str(time.time() - last_time))
        keys = key_check()

        # pause agent
        if 'T' in keys:
            if paused:
                paused = False
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                paused = True
                ReleaseKey(Space)
                time.sleep(1)

main()
```

I expected the agent to be right around 98% of the time so it should get at least a score higher than 2 but that is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds really cool and something like what SethBling did for MarI/O.  If you used the model to train itself based on recognizing obstacles in the displayed pixels and a goal of highest score I think it is feasible to hit a target score eventually.

Video Demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44

Source Code: https://pastebin.com/ZZmSNaHX

```
-- MarI/O by SethBling
-- Feel free to use this code, but please do not redistribute it.
-- Intended for use with the BizHawk emulator and Super Mario World or Super Mario Bros. ROM.
-- For SMW, make sure you have a save state named "DP1.state" at the beginning of a level,
-- and put a copy in both the Lua folder and the root directory of BizHawk.
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like training the model to recognise which image is a 'jump' image and which is a 'do nothing' image and act accordingly instead of recognising pixels representing obstacles. This method seems a lot harder but I was just wondering if it works or I am forced to do something similar to what you have suggested. Is that feasible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thinking of just looking at snapshots and how there are pipes at different heights I think it would be important to know a few things to interpret to tell it to jump or not.  for instance bird_height, top_pipe_min, bot_pipe_max to find the safe to fly area, the rate at which the bird is falling from heightn to heightn+1, the rate that height increases upon each press of jump from jumpn to jumpn+1.  You would hate to have it be in the safe area and hit the pipes while inside it but also wouldn't want the guy to fall off the screen

Comment: Thanks for replying, I want to confirm something now. The link below is actually what I tried to base my model on but I ended up following another tutorial to use keras. In the link, Chintan did the same thing as I’m trying to do but with fifa, however, he used LSTMs and SSD. I don’t see any code that specifies things like player_to_goal_distance or player_to_goal_angle to help in the playing of the game. Am I wrong to say he just fed sets of images with actions as the labels and the model figured which set of images required which action(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea. I have no idea how flappy bird works, but let me ask you this question: if you as an intelligent human being were to look at a single frame generated by the game, would you be able to recognise that you should or shouldn't hit spacebar? Is that enough information, or do you need to know more contextual information as well? If it is enough, then with a large enough training set you could probably get a reasonable result.

Note though, an accuracy of 98% does not mean much. If for example this data is heavily weighted to 0 (do nothing), i.e. doing nothing the right answer 90% of the time, then your model will learn that simple outputting 0 **100%** of the time will make it 90% accurate. You need to look at other metrics to understand how well the model is performing (confusion matrices, precision-recall, ROC-curves, AUC) etc.

If you've discovered inbalance, you then need a strategy to balance of the training data, such as class weighting or upsampling a single class

Comment: I am aware of the class imbalance. I made sure to train on data that is 50% doing nothing and 50% jumping. I was also thinking about using LSTM so as to solve the single frame problem but I wanted to try this first so as to see if it is doable. Human-wise, single frame should be enough unless I’m missing something. Will try other metrics! Thanks